# Не завершается процесс C#

Tags: c#

Имеется код, который должен завершать процесс, который был запущен из указанной папки:

```
namespace newkill
{
    class Program
    {  
        static void Main() { }

        string path = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\WindowsW0W32\";
        public static void KillProcesses(string path)
        {
            Process.GetProcesses() // получаем все процессы
                .Where(p => CheckIfProcessFileEquals(p, path)) // берем только те, в которых пути к файлу совпадают
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(p => p.Kill()); // убиваем каждый
        }

        private static bool CheckIfProcessFileEquals(Process process, string path)
        {
            try
            {
                return process.MainModule.FileName.Equals(path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); // сравниваем пути, инорим кейс
            }
            catch (Win32Exception)
            {
                return false; // если MainModule недоступен - скипаем
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл запущен именно из этой папки - `C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\WindowsW0W32\` но после выполнения программы процесс не убивается. Что может быть не так? Версия .NET 3.5

Comment: Вообще-то этот код смотрит по **полному пути к файлу** (включая имя), а не по папке, в которой этот файл находится. Да и к тому же вы не вызываете эту функцию.

Comment: @ASG17, т.е. мне нужно вот так указать - C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\WindowsW0W32\file.exe?

Comment: @ASG17, я указал вот так - C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\WindowsW0W32\file.exe, но всё равно процесс не убивается.

Comment: Естественно. Вы же не вызываете функцию (я уже написал это [вторым предложением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683862/#comment1005495_683862))

Comment: Переписать на цикл и подебажить.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас выполниться ровно то, что написано в `Main`:

```
static void Main() { }
```

Т.е **ни-че-го**.

Исправляйте:

```
static void Main()
{
    var path = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\WindowsW0W32\file.exe";
    KillProcesses(path);
}
```

Так же советую получать путь к `AppData` с помощью `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` и использовать [`Path.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) для конкатенации пути к файлу:

```
static void Main()
{
    var path = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
        "Roaming",
        "WindowsW0W32",
        "file.exe");
    KillProcesses(path);
}
```

Comment: @ASG17, вот теперь точно всё работает, благодарю!